# Body padding and scrollbars with Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Recently, I had a problem with the color of the footer at the bootstrap.

I solved this by creating a div and eliminating the extra padding of the native body.

You can find the code in basic version : jsfiddle.net/wctGM/9/

In the mobile version, however, the **scroll bars** appear, and checking through the means of google chrome, I have not found anything that could create this.

**Can you explain the reason for this?**

**Thanks in advance** to everyone, I hope someone can solve the problem

Comment: http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/index.html

Comment: Thanks for the comment, but I do not understand what you want to tell me with this link

Answer (score 0):

The following ideas may cause the scroll bars to go away:

Give your div a width of say 90%

```
div
{
  width:90%;
}
```

add box-sizing:border-box to your div.

```
div.container {
 padding : 0 20px;
 -moz-box-sizing:border-box;
 box-sizing:border-box;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the advice, but unfortunately it does not work.

Could I have the effect of the footer of another color without adding div as I did?

Comment: check out this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/danield770/wctGM/11/ I removed 2 of your divs... although I'm not sure exactly what you need